# How to get price as string from DynamoDB data

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have data in my DynamoDB with have 4 parameter, priceId, symbol, price and time

Here my DynamoDB database

[image: Price table Quotes]

My database has primaryKey is symbol and sortKey is Time. How to get list of price from my database using symbol and time for search ? because this is my first to use DynamoDB here.

Answer (score 0):

Since `symbol` and `Time` together are your key, there is only one item matching any particular symbol and time that you say are waiting for, so the result is just one item, not a list, and you can get it with a `GetItem` operation.

If, despite what you explained above, what you actually want to do is to get the list of all items matching just the symbol, and sort this list by time, then you should call the `Query` operation for the particular `symbol`.

Please refer to the documentation of your favorite AWS SDK in your favorite language for an example how to call these operations.